# Python regular expression date

Tags: python

How can I use Python regular expressions on the following variables to extract the date?

```
a = 'abc_de_00_abcd_20130605.zip'

a = 'abc_de_20130605_00_abcd.zip'
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
re.match(r'[0-9]{8}',a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) checks if the pattern can be found at the *start* of the string (it's as if you had asked for `^[0-9]{8}` instead of `[0-9]{8}`).

You want [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) since your date string can be at different positions in your file name:

```
re.search(r'[0-9]{8}', a)  # results in a match
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use re.search method. re.match tries to match the entire input string. What you need is

```
re.search(r'[0-9]{8}', a).group()
```